# Normal and log return plotting in R and corresponding returns

Tags: r, logging, plot

I have a data sheet, with a lot of var. companies with the DAX index. 
I'm trying to get a time series for BMW and SIEMENS and also the log return from them. 
Sorry, can not attach pics...
Sample:

```
Positions   ALLIANZ.HLDG.   COMMERZBANK DRESDNER.BANK   BMW SCHERING    BASF
01/01/1973  155.51  147.41  18.40   103.97  36.88   14.96
01/02/1973  155.51  147.41  18.40   109.05  37.44   15.43
01/03/1973  160.58  149.14  18.80   109.83  37.79   15.61
01/04/1973  162.27  152.05  18.91   110.81  37.86   15.85
01/05/1973  164.30  152.05  18.89   109.44  37.44   15.75
01/08/1973  164.30  152.25  18.99   109.05  37.79   15.80
```

The datas are from 197X, but I need datas just from 02.01.1989, till the end of the sheet.

The other is to extract data from 1996 (BMW, SIEMENS). And Calculate the corresponding returns on that specific year. 
I'm totally stuck and would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Please help me how to calculate it in R.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Make sure to include: 1. sample input, 2. sample output, 3. what have you tried and what error message you got

Comment: I try my best, since I'm new here, I cannot add pictures, it makes a bit more difficult.

Comment: *Please do NOT add pictures!* We cannot copy paste from them. Add sample text. Not the full text you have, but a representative sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the `quantmod` package. Calling your table above `df`,

```
library(quantmod)
df$Positions <- as.Date(df$Positions, format="%m/%d/%Y")
rownames(df) <- df$Positions
bmw.xts <- xts(df$BMW,order.by=df$Positions)
periodReturn(bmw.xts,period="daily")
#            daily.returns
# 1973-01-01   0.000000000
# 1973-01-02   0.048860248
# 1973-01-03   0.007152682
# 1973-01-04   0.008922881
# 1973-01-05  -0.012363505
# 1973-01-08  -0.003563596

periodReturn(bmw.xts,period="daily", type="log")
#            daily.returns
# 1973-01-01   0.000000000
# 1973-01-02   0.047704097
# 1973-01-03   0.007127223
# 1973-01-04   0.008883307
# 1973-01-05  -0.012440569
# 1973-01-08  -0.003569961

periodReturn(bmw.xts,period="daily", subset="1973-01-03::")
#            daily.returns
# 1973-01-03   0.007152682
# 1973-01-04   0.008922881
# 1973-01-05  -0.012363505
# 1973-01-08  -0.003563596
```

The way your table is set up, the first column, containing the dates, is loaded into a column `Positions`, which is probably not what you want. Nevertheless I left it that way to avoid confusion. So `Positions` is the timestamp in this example. These have to be converted to dates with the `as.Date(...)` function. Then, we create an xts time series, `bmw.xts` from the `BMW` column. Then we can use the quantmod function `periodReturn(...)` to generate returns. The `subset=` string is formatted as `"start::end"`. If end is missing, the time series is taken to the last row.

Finally, an example of plotting

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)   # for melt(...)
basf.xts <- xts(df$BASF,order.by=df$Positions)
returns <- data.frame(df$Positions,
                      periodReturn(bmw.xts,period="daily",type="log"),
                      periodReturn(basf.xts,period="daily",type="log"))
colnames(returns)=c("Date","BMW","BASF")
gg <- melt(returns, id="Date", variable.name="Stock", value.name="Log.Return")
ggplot(gg, aes(x=Date, y=Log.Return, color=Stock))+
  geom_point()+ geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: How can I extract datas from a period? 
> subset(df$BMW, "1996-01-01::") -->not working
And how can I calculate the corresponding returns of the two data? For example BMW in 1996 and BASF in 1996? Thank you so much for your kind help.

Comment: Did you study the code? You have to convert `df$BMW` to an xts object first.

Comment: bmw.xts is done. How should I continue? Please help me how should I calculate a corresponding return and estimate beta?

Comment: So `periodReturn(bmw.xts,period="daily", subset="1996-01-01::")` will give you daily returns from 1996-01-01 until the end. To get beta, you can use the `CAPM.beta(...)` function in the `PerformanceAnalytics` package. See [the documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PerformanceAnalytics/PerformanceAnalytics.pdf). Also, here is [an example](http://www.perdomocore.com/2012/using-r-and-quantmod-to-find-cost-of-equity/).